# SSL JSON - C# to vb.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ssl, certificate

I have a C# code that connects with SSL. 
I am trying for 3 days to write the same code in VB.Net 
but it doesn't work.

Here is the C# code:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
var response = client.PostAsync("GetRequestOperation", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
response.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var data = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var jObj = JObject.Parse(data.Result);
```

How do I write it in VB.Net?

Comment: This is off topic for SO, but I will give you a tip. Download Telerik's JustDecompile (it's free and I have no affiliation), open your C# dll, and choose VB from the drop down in the menu bar to see how it translates the code.

Comment: Google for some translation tools.

Comment: i tryied google translation but i still cant fix the code... here is the vb code i recived   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(o, certificate, chain, errors) True
                    Dim response = client.PostAsync("GalaRequest", request, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                    response.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
                    Dim data = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                    Dim jObj = JObject.Parse(data.Result) still i cant define respones , data and ,jObj ...